# Xampp files in Vagrant: No input file specified.

Tags: laravel, xampp, vagrant, homestead

I am new on vagrant. I am using Laravel Homestead Improved by following [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-get-homestead-vagrant-vm-running/)
link. I want to map my existing code on vagrant which is inside my xampp installation. Here is my Homestead.yaml file contents.

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

sites:
    - map: myapp.com
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

folders:
    - map: /opt/lampp/htdocs/codebase
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Although when I run the following command

```
cd Code/
```

it shows my code but on browser when I run http://myapp.com:8000/ it shows "No input file specified."

Answer (score 0):

By default a webserver usually looks for `index.html` then `index.php`, neither of these files are in your `/home/vagrant/Code` folder which is why you're getting the "No input file specified" error.

On your sites section, you should map the domain to your `public` folder of Laravel. So in this case it should likely be `/home/vagrant/Code/public`

Comment: okay I understand but I am not pointing laravel here. Its codeiginter.

Answer (score 0):

You mapped `codebase` to `Code`, and you mapped `myapp.com` to `Code`.

If you currently have an app in `codebase/app1/index.php`, then this wouldn't work because `myapp.com` is looking for `index.php` inside `Code`.

Thus, you need to access either: `myapp.com:8000/app1` OR you need to remap sites like so (and do this for every site/app folder inside `codebase`):

```
sites:
    - map: myapp.com
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/app1
```

*Note that you need to replace `app1` with whatever you called your app's folder in XAMPP*